さすが vs. それでこそ - "Just what you'd expect from"
Differing from それこそ, それでこそ seems to have a function to act very much like さすが and essentially mean "just what you'd expect from".
Here's an example from Kill la Kill where the main character is about to reface an opponent:

Ryuko:さっさとこの間のケリつけようじゃねえか
今度はあたしも逃げやしねえ
Sanageyama:フフフッそれでこそ纏流子
Time to finish our fight from the other day.
I ain't gonna run this
time!
You wouldn't be Ryuko Matoi if you did.

So it means something here like "That's just like (Ryuko Matoi)".
It seems that さすが could also work here if I'm not mistaken, so how might they differ here and in general?

They are semantically close, but more literally, それでこそ means "that (act) is very [somebody] who I expect" while さすが means "never-failing-to-amaze". So それでこそ leans more toward "it's so you" and さすが more "you did it again" sentiments respectively.
By the way, それ is the subject in それこそ A だ so that it means "that is the very A", but not in それでこそ A だ, which means "being (like) that is the very A". They are thus hardly interchangeable in my opinion.

I thought I could write a more detailed answer that justifies how this nuance arises from the etymology. But as I started writing, I just couldn't find words to express the point. Actually, I'm not sure my original idea was sound. That said, I think the で does add a fair bit of meaning, because we're contemplating a possible action Ryuko would take.

@KarlKnechtel I would say that さすが is a totally opaque word in the modern language. You can go back to its origin (like "(while) being (known to) do so") but the connotation has changed a lot.

That's a shame. I was having fun trying to wrap my head around the metaphor implied by the kanji.

@KarlKnechtel Ahh... I'd be excited to know where the kanji came from if you have any idea though ;)
